# PHP: memory issues while looping thousand of items

Tags: php, loops, optimization

*This is a WordPress with Woocommerce project.*

I have to loop an array with more than 200 thousand of items. Every item is an order's ID in the data base. I have to sum the value of every order's meta to get the total sum. But the loop allways ends with memory issue.

Here is my code:

```php
function woq_orders_total(){
    $orders = get_option( 'woq_orders_ids' ); // array of IDs
    $meta = array();

    $i = 0;
    foreach( $orders as $order ) :
        $meta[] = get_post_meta( $order, '_order_total', true );
        if ( $i % 500 == 0 )
            sleep( 5 ); // stop for 5 seconds every 500 items

        $i++;
    endforeach;

    update_option( 'woq_orders_total', array_sum( $meta ) );
}
```

I've try stoping every 100 items, but the problem persists. This works well with a few numbers of items, but not with this big amount.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Any reason you need an array?  Why not perform the calculation with addition within your foreach loop?

Comment: You can increase the memory limit. https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit But do you really need to keep all metadata in memory?

Comment: Why do you think sleep(5) would have any effect on memory?

Comment: @Devon Show the solution in an answer.

Comment: @Barmar I use sleep(5) because I saw that solution in Internet, then I thought it would help... I'm trying to stop for a while, then continue.

Comment: Do you think your computer is getting tired and needs to rest a few seconds, like a runner? Do you think it cleans up memory while it's sleeping?

Comment: If you saw that solution somewhere, it must have been for a different problem, like an API with a rate limit.

Comment: Each call to `get_post_meta()` in your loop goes through a [wild trail of functions](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) and potentially database calls. Munch munch goes your server resources. Just write a simple SQL query along the lines of `SELECT SUM(_order_total) AS total FROM orders WHERE order_id IN ( ...IDs... )` instead of grinding your server with WP built-ins invoked in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution thanks to the comment by **[Markus AO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76326536/php-memory-issues-while-looping-thousand-of-items#comment134594754_76326536)**

Now my code looks like this:

```php
function woq_orders_total(){
    global $wpdb;
    $orders = get_option( 'woq_orders_ids' );
    $orders = join( ',', $orders );
    $meta_key = '_order_total';

    $total = $wpdb->get_var(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "
            SELECT SUM(meta_value)
            FROM $wpdb->postmeta
            WHERE meta_key = %s
            AND post_id IN ({$orders})
            ",
            $meta_key
        )
    );

    update_option( 'woq_orders_total', $total );
}
```

Also these comment in `$wpdb` documentation help a lot https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/#comment-1975

Thanks you all.

Comment: Glad to see you took up the straight SQL approach. I bet it takes more like 0.2 seconds than 2000000 seconds. Be careful with WP built-in functions, look up the WP codebase for anything recurring to verify what all may be going on behind the scenes. I had my first traumatic encounters in 2014 with the BuddyPress package where, for some peculiar reason, most pages were making [200 to 300+ queries](https://twitter.com/CodeSatori/status/504775322923847681) to the database, mostly to terms. While in actuality, probably more like 10 or 20 queries at the most were necessary. Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks @MarkusAO . Yes, I've been working with WordPress for some years, but building normal sites, in this project I face for first time a big amount of data. Now I know the big difference between `$wpdb` and the built in functions and classes made for quering the data base. Thanks a lot 

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to read all the data into the array to sum them up.
You only need to store the sum.

```php
function woq_orders_total(){
    $orders = get_option( 'woq_orders_ids' ); // array of IDs
    $total = 0;

    foreach( $orders as $order ) :
        $total += (float)get_post_meta( $order, '_order_total', true );
    endforeach;

    update_option( 'woq_orders_total', $total);
}
```